# How do I append a new hash to an array of hashes?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, perl-data-structures

If I wanted to add a new hash to all the arrays in the `mother_hash` using a loop, what would be the syntax?

My hash:

```
my %mother_hash = (
    'daughter_hash1' => [ 
        { 
          'e' => '-4.3', 
          'seq' => 'AGGCACC', 
          'end' => '97', 
          'start' => '81' 
        } 
    ],
    'daughter_hash2' => [ 
        { 
          'e' => '-4.4', 
          'seq' => 'CAGT', 
          'end' => '17', 
          'start' => '6' 
        }, 
        { 
          'e' => '-4.1', 
          'seq' => 'GTT', 
          'end' => '51', 
          'start' => '26' 
        }, 
        { 
          'e' => '-4.1', 
          'seq' => 'TTG', 
          'end' => '53', 
          'start' => '28' 
        } 
    ],
    #...
);
```

Comment: Try this: `push @{ $_ }, \%new_hash for (values %mother_hash);`

Comment: Thanks, will do.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Please copy and paste your comment into an answer, if you please. That is a very elegant answer.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms Thanks, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a hash of arrays of hashes and want to add a new hash to 
the end of each of the arrays, you can do:

```
push @{ $_ }, \%new_hash for (values %mother_hash);
```

This loop iterates over the values of `%mother_hash` (which are array refs in this case) and setting `$_` for each iteration. Then in each iteration, we push the reference to the new hash `%new_hash` to the end of that array.

Answer (score 2):

First I would point out the daughter hashes aren't hashes but arrays of anonymous hashes. To add another daughter hash:

```
$mother_hash{daughter_hash3} = [ { %daughter_hash3 } ];
```

This creates an anonymous array that contains an anonymous hash with the contents of `%daughter_hash3`.

For a loop:

```
$mother_hash{$daughter_hash_key} = [ { %daughter_hash } ];
```

where `$daughter_hash_key` is a string contain the key for the `%mother_hash` and `%daughter_hash` is the hash to add.

To add another hash to a daughter array with key `$daughter_hash_key`:

```
push @{ $mother_hash{$daughter_hash_key} }, { %daughter_hash };
```

I know ti's complicated but I suggest you use `Data::Dumper` to dump the contents of `%mother_hash` each time thru the loop to see if it grows correctly.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%mother_hash;
```

See [`perldoc Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) for details..

`Data::Dumper` is a standard module that comes with Perl. For a list of standard modules, see [`perldoc perlmodlib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodlib.html).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it @Shawn!

Answer (score 1):

`mother_hash` is a hash of arrays of hashes.

To add another top-level array of hashes.

```
%mother_hash{$key} = [ { stuff }, { stuff } ];
```

To add another entry to an existing array

```
push @{%mother_hash{'key'}} { stuff };
```

To add another entry to the hash in the embedded array

```
%{@{%mother_hash{'top_key'}}[3]}{'new_inner_key'} = value;
```

When confused and attempting to match up the "types" of hash / array / scalar containing a hash reference / array reference, you can use the following technique

```
 use Data::Dumper;
 $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
 printf("mother_hash reference = %s\n", Dumper(\%mother_hash));
 printf("mother_hash of key 'top_key' = %s\n", Dumper(%mother_hash{top_key}));
```

and so on to find your way through a large data structure and validate that you are narrowing down to the region you want to access or alter.

Comment: Thanks very much @Edwin!